# Sed substitution has no effect

Tags: bash, sed

```
#! /bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2

i= ... # i is a filename generated with find command
j="$(echo $i | sed -E 's/$A/$B/')"
```

I am trying to change part of `i`, (`A` in this case), into something else (`B` in this case), and store it in `j`.

I've executed this, but apparently `j` is identical to `i`. I'm pretty sure I've put command line arguments correctly.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You need to use double quotes for your `sed` command for the shell to expand the variables i.e. `sed -E "s/$A/$B/"`

Comment: Check if `j="${i/$A/$B}"` is OK too. From your example it seems like `sed` is not necessary - but can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace single quotes with double quotes in `'s/$A/$B/'`. The following command should work.

```
j=$( echo $i | sed -E "s/$A/$B/" )
```

Comment: @MisaLazovic There must be *no spaces* around a variable assignment in Bash.